# How to figure out if today comes between 2 given dates in fetchXML

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-365

I have 2 dates column in dynamics 365 CRM, one is Travel pass valid from and 
another is Travel pass valid to...

I need to know know the travel pass is valid today but I am unable to find a way to do this?

There is operation, onOrAfter but I am not sure how can I say onOrAfter Today

Comment: Not sure if you'll be able to do this in a view because of the `today` requirement. You could build this in a report though

Answer (score 0):

If you writing the query in code you just need to input today's date into the query.

E.g.

```
Valid from - on or before - 16 Jan (today's date)

And

Valid to - on or after - 16 Jan (today's date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting options include:

```
`<condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="2014-06-20" />`
```

OR with the greater or equal operator `ge`:

`<condition attribute="createdon" operator="ge" value="07/01/2014" />`

OR if you want to get down to the second:

`<condition attribute="modifiedon" value="2014-04-23T14:05:18-04:00" operator="gt"/>
<condition attribute="modifiedon" value="2014-04-23T14:48:37-04:00" operator="lt"/>`